# Mention/tag user via SE mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, comment-replies, autocomplete

There is one minor feature that won't work in the Stack Exchange Android app. Mentioning/tagging a user is not working like in the desktop browser. It won't display a user suggestion.

So, it would be such a pain when mentioning some user with long name or weird characters.

Is it bug, or has this feature not been added yet?

Comment: The "mention" works just fine, what you mean is the autocomplete is missing. The reason is that we don't need it: you can tap any comment, and there is a "reply" button on top which automatically insert `@name` to the box.

Comment: @ShadowWizard cool, just tried this